# Python regex optional group with capturing group not working

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling with a regex in python. I've spent several hours trying to figure out what is wrong.
Here is my content:

```
Some Title - Description (Gold Edition)
Some Title - Description
```

I need to match `Some Title` and optional `Gold` word in brackets.

I've tried the following regex https://regex101.com/r/9MNYZl/1 :

```
(.*)\-.*(?:\((.*)[Ee]dition\))*?
```

But it doesn't capture the word before `Edition`.

One interesting thing that I tried this for `PHP` and it worked fine.

I have no ideas what is wrong, please help to solve the issue.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first `.*` in your pattern will match until the end of the string, then it will backtrack to match the `-` and the second `.*` will match again till the end of the string.

As this part of the pattern `(?:\((.*)[Ee]dition\))*?` is optional, the pattern will suffice at the end of the string.

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) with an optional non capturing group.

To match the first word after the opening parenthesis you could match 1+ word chars `\w+` or a broader match using `\S+`

```
^([^-]+)-[^\()]+(?:\((\S+) [Ee]dition\))?
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^-]+` Match 1+ times any char except -
- `)-` Close group 1 and match -
- `[^()]+` Match 1+ times any char except `(` or `)`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times a non whitespace char
  - `[Ee]dition` Match a space and [eE]dition
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gwBlhf/1)

To capture all until the edition in group 2 instead of a single word:

```
^([^-]+)-[^()]+(?:\(([^()]+) [Ee]dition\))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/psZNgL/1)